# Cowboys and Bicycles

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

There are 4 cowboys and 53 bicycles.  One of the cowboys is shot by the others.  Why?  The correct answer should be able to adequately explain the circumstances of the shooting.

**Hint 1**

> This takes place in a saloon.

**Hint 2**

> The cowboy is shot because of the bicycles.

(This is my first question here so please feel free to tag / retag as needed)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The bicycles are

> [Bicycle brand playing cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_Playing_Cards). The cowboy had an extra (probably an ace, the no-good so-and-so)

Comment: Haha, that didn't take long at all.  Good job :)